# Search Only if not Null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, if-statement

I am currently writing a search function to search tickets by a Ticket owner, Ticket Tech, Status, etc.  However I thought I can just put in if statements in the middle of the Linq statement testing if not null, unfortunately I am getting an error on the if statement that I have in the LINQ statement. Here is my controller code:

```
 public ActionResult TechSearchTickets()
        {
            ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.TicketStatuses, "UserId", "FullName");
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users
                                                .Where(u => u.Status == 1 || u.RoleID == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")), "UserId", "FullName");
            ViewBag.TechId = new SelectList(db.Users
                                                .Where(u => u.Status == 1 || u.RoleID == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")), "UserId", "FullName");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TechSearchTickets(SearchTickets searchTickets)
        {

            var model = db.Tickets
                    .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
                    if (searchTickets.TechnicianId != null)
                    {
                        .Where(t => t.TechnicianId == g)
                    }
                    .Where(t => t.TicketStatusId == new Guid("553F4C93-4A72-44BD-A9CE-FAB4F87D4E08"))
                    .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate)
                    .ToList();

            return View("TechClosed", model);


            return View();
        }
```

Comment: does it even compile?

Comment: What is g in: .Where(t => t.TechnicianId == g) ???

Comment: Yeah `g` isn't defined here. Perhaps it was just left as g instead of showing the techId for obscurity? Or maybe defined elsewhere in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close. You just need to add a few semicolons, and `model=model`s.

```
var model = db.Tickets
  .Include(t => t.TicketNotes);
if (searchTickets.TechnicianId != null)
{
  model=model.Where(t => t.TechnicianId==g);
}
model=model.Where(t => t.TicketStatusId==new Guid("553F4C93-4A72-44BD-A9CE-FAB4F87D4E08"))
  .OrderBy(t => t.OpenDate);
var result=model.ToList();
```

Comment: This is a very good point to make and more viable than the other option I suggested (now removed). +1

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ.  I prefer not depending on the LINQ query provider to figure out how to optimize that stuff out if I can help it.  The SQL LINQ provider is pretty good, but not all of them are.

Comment: I completely agree. For example, the mysql provider has many issues with it (I have even submitted bugs to oracle regarding it). Any time that the query provider can be avoided such as by conditionally building a query using chaining as shown here is definitely best practice.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you that works.  

For everyone who was asking me about g - I did not define it yet but I was getting an error on the Where clause itself so I needed to fix that.